# NavCtrl: keep page in cache after it's popped

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

On the home page of my app, I navigate to another page using:
`this.navCtrl.push(Page2);`

When I click the "back" button on Page2 to go back to the home page, and then navigate back to Page2, I notice that `ionViewDidLoad()` is called again, meaning Page2 wasn't in the cache anymore.

I guess this is because Page2 was on top of the stack, and is then removed from the stack.

Is there a way to keep the current state of the page? On Page2, there's a progress bar and I want the user to be able to see the progress when he uses the back button and navigates back to the page. The progress bar can't be reset

Comment: you could save the state of the progress bar in a singleton service maybe

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible as you've said, when you navigate back the view is destroyed.
What you can do is create a custom component that will hold the progress bar.

- You'll initialize the component in your home page so it'll be in the bottom of the stack and will only be destroyed if the app closes.
- In your page2 you'll call the function to initialize the progress bar, this function need to be in the component.
- Since Ionic stacks page over page, you'll need to use some css on your component, like `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; heigth: 100%; z-index: 9999`, and if you need to hide, just have a boolean variable that you set as true false and apply css with ngClass.

If you need to understand how custom components are created, follow this tutorial by [Josh Morony](https://www.joshmorony.com/custom-components-in-ionic-2/)

Hope it helps :)